# Confusing values when copying to another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, io

I am trying to copy values from one array to another in C. The original array is of type `long int`, and it is inputted to the function as `*pixel_frequency`. The array I want to copy to is `temp`, and it is a 2D array. However, when I try to copy the values, `pixel_frequency` is fine but `temp` gives strange results. Below is the relevant code and some sample output.

Code:

```
struct node *generate_nodes(long int *pixel_frequency) {
    int i;
    int temp[max_value + 1][2];

    for (i = 0; i < (max_value + 1); i++) {
        temp[i][0] = i;
        temp[i][1] = pixel_frequency[i];
        printf("Frequency for %d is %d\n", temp[i][0], temp[i][1]);
    }
...
```

Output (each frequency is supposed to be 256):

```
Frequency for 0 is 150160
Frequency for 1 is 256
Frequency for 2 is 256
Frequency for 3 is 256
Frequency for 4 is 255
...
Frequency for 254 is 892677956
Frequency for 255 is 1868789101
```

Comment: shouldn't `temp` array be of type `long int`, you are demoting from `long int` to `int`. Also what do you mean by `strange results`?

Comment: In a separate function, I defined `pixel_frequency` to have `max_value + 1` entries. By "strange results", I mean that the output is a strange number like `892677956` instead of `256` as it should be.

Comment: The code you've posted does not have the problem you describe, which is why it's always recommended that one post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code you're displaying has nothing to do with what the values in the `pixel_frequency` array are which you've said are incorrect.  Have you checked that they actually have the values you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example version of code using your code snippet, take care of the return type and other things.

Instead of using a global variable for array size, you can pass it as a function argument so , it will be easy to identify the size of array you passed.

```
void generate_nodes(long int *pixel_frequency, size_t size) {
    size_t i;
    long int temp[size][2];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp[i][0] = i;
        temp[i][1] = pixel_frequency[i];
        printf("Frequency for %ld is %ld\n", temp[i][0], temp[i][1]);
    }
}
```

If you have declared `pixel_frequency` as a local variable in a function and used the address of array after the variable went out of scope, will lead to undefined behaviour.

```
int main(void) {
    size_t max_len = 5000;
    size_t i;
    long int* pixel_frequency = malloc(max_len*sizeof(long int));

    for( i = 0; i < max_len; ++i) {
        pixel_frequency[i] = (i%256);
    }

    generate_nodes(pixel_frequency, max_len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The original function returns a pointer to a **node** structure and your function returns a **void**.

Comment: The OP only submitted a fragment from the original function, the problem seems to lie in the caller's handling of the `pixel_frequency` array.  Sumon submitted a complete program with the OP's fragment with better handling of array boundaries and should confirm that the offending code is elsewhere.