# Value of array changes while copying to another array

Tags: c++, arrays

My objective is to create a pulse mode modulation program that would accept the amplitude and time period , and change it to binary.
I looked into this problem, found i was using a local variable in a function so it was going out of scope, changed the code but the problem persists.
The code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define SAMPLE_SIZE 12

class sine_curve
{
public:


int get(double amplitude, double time, double *x, double frequency, int sample)
{
    for(sample = 0; sample <= time; sample++)
    {
        x[sample] = amplitude * sin(2 * 3.142 * frequency * sample);
        std::cout << x[sample]<<"\t";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
return *x;    }

};

int main()
{

double amplitude, time, frequency, x[SAMPLE_SIZE], y[SAMPLE_SIZE];
int sample;

std::cout << "Enter amplitude: ";
std::cin >> amplitude;
std::cout << "Enter time: ";
std::cin >> time;
sine_curve sine;
sine.get(amplitude, time, x, frequency,sample);

for(sample = 0; sample <= time; sample++)
{
    std::cout << x[sample] << std::endl;
}

std::cout << std::endl;

*y = *x;
for(sample = 0; sample <= time; sample++)
{
    std::cout << y[sample] << std::endl;
}
}
```

The output ::
    Enter amplitude: 23
    Enter time: 3
    0   1.00344e-307    2.00687e-307    3.01031e-307    
    0
    1.00344e-307
    2.00687e-307
    3.01031e-307

0
   2.07377e-317
   5.61259e-321
   2.12203e-314

When I print the array y, the value changes.
i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758249/confusing-values-when-copying-to-another-array) link and the rest I don't remember but their answer was also the same.

Comment: `*y = *x` this is how you copy an array?

Comment: `*y = *x;` -- What do you think this does?  If you want "natural looking syntax", then your best bet is to use `std::vector`, as copying a vector would look like your attempt at copying arrays.

Comment: Unrelated, `frequency`  sent to your `sine.get`, is uninitialized. So your code is already invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I was sending the address of the array to be copied from to the array to be copied into.

Comment: @SiddhantGhosh  Arrays are dumb.  You cannot copy them using `=`.  You have to actually call a function to do it, whether it is `memcpy`, `std::copy`, or your own loop.  Use a smarter container, such as `std::array` or `std::vector`, which know how to copy using `=`.

Comment: how do you copy an array then ?@tobi303

Comment: Ok, thank you @PaulMcKenzie i will do as you suggested.

Comment: @SiddhantGhosh Use `std::array`, not dumb arrays.  Then your code would look (again) more "natural", i.e. using `=` to copy.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
*y = *x;
```

The issue is that arrays cannot be copied using `=`.  A function has to be called to do this work, whether it is `std::copy`, `memcpy`, your own `for` loop, etc.

To alleviate this, you could use `std::array` instead of regular arrays, and with minimal changes to the code, since `std::array` overloads `operator =` so that the copy can be done using a more "natural" syntax.

If `x` and `y` are

`std::array<double, SAMPLE_SIZE>`

then the copying is simply:

`y = x;`

[Live Example using std::array](http://ideone.com/PVosMi)

Note that there are issues with calculations and uninitialized variable usage that are out-of-scope of the given issue of array copying.  Those issues you will need to resolve.

Comment: Worked like a charm.